# Harmonic function as real part of any analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I denote with $\phi(x,y)$ a hamornic function. I would like to show that $\phi$ is the real part of any analytic function $f(z)$ of the form $$f(z)=2\phi\left(\frac{z+1}{2},\frac{z-1}{2i}\right)-\phi(1,0)+ic$$ where c is a real constant and provided that the RHS exists.

My idea was to consider $$g(z,\bar{z})=\phi\left(\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}),\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z})\right)+i\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}),\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z})\right)$$

and set this equal to $f(z)=g(z,\bar{z})$ with $\bar{z}=1$, but is this helpful?

Remark: In the end I would like to find an analytic function whose real part is $\tan^{-1}y/x$, my lecture notes states that the obvious function is $-i\log z$ but I do not see why this is so obvious.

Comment: Search Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, that would show that the real part of an analytic function was harmonic, but not the converse without a little work. I'm sure the poster is aware of the cauchy-riemann equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your question makes little sense to me:

- $\phi\left(\frac{z+1}{2},\frac{z-1}{2i}\right)$ is not defined since $\phi(x,y)$ only exists for $x$ and $y$ real
- Your candidate function $f$ has constant imaginary part, which is impossible for a non constant holomorphic function.

It's a classical fact or exercise that a harmonic function is (at least locally) the real part of a holomorphic function, and that this holomorphic function is unique up to a (purely imaginary) additive  contant (and this function looks nothing like what you wrote). You should try to do this exercise (use the Cauchy-Riemann equations), it would be instructive.

As for your example, I can explain it to you: recall the principal value logarithm is $\log z = \ln |z| + i \operatorname{Arg}(z)$ (for $z \notin \mathbb{R}_-$), where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the principal value argument of $z$, *i.e.* in $(-\pi, \pi]$. In your problem, I'm assuming you are working in the half-plane $H = \{z\in \mathbb{C}, ~\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$. For $z \in H$, it's not hard to check that $\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$, where $z = x+iy$. It follows that $\operatorname{Re}(-i\log(z)) = \operatorname{Arg}(z) = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you also have an idea how to find an analytic fct whose real part is $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: yes: take $1/z$

Comment: Is there a reason $\phi$ is not defined? If $\phi$ is harmonic then it may be expressed everywhere as a power series in which we may plug in $z,\overline{z}$

Answer (score 2):

Your first phrase should read "... is the real part of *some* analytic function...".

As Seub said, your first formula does not makes sense. Your second formula makes sense, but the RHS depends only of $z$ ($\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$!), so $\bar{z}=1$ is absurd.

The usual solution is take $g=\phi_x-i\phi_y$ (the presumptive derivative of $f=\phi+i\psi$), check analiticity with Cauchy-Riemann and integrate (calculate a primitive). Warning: the topology of the domain is important, as your example proves.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am very late but I 'd like to say something :)

Let $D\subset$ be a domain in the complex plan and $h$ be harmonic in $D$ then there is $f\in O(D)$ ( holomorphic functions) so that $h=\log|f|.$

\begin{proof}:

For $m>0$ let $(D_m)_m$ be a sequence of open disc so that $D_m\cap D_{m+1}\not=\varnothing$, $\bar D_m\subset D$ and $\cup_m D_m=D.$\
For each $m>0$ we construct (by induction) a holomorphic function $f_m$ defined on $ D_1\cup\cdots\cup D_m$ so that $\Re(f_m)=h.$\

For $m=1$, as $h$ is harmonic, there is $f_1\in O(D_1)$ so that $h=\Re(f_1)$ in  $D_1.$
For $m=2$ there is $g\in O(D_2)$ so that $h=\Re(g)$ in $D_2.$ Since $f_1$ and $g$ are holomorphic and $\Re(g)=\Re(f)$ on $D_1\cap D_2$ we infer that there is $c_1\in R$ so that $f_1=g+ic_1$ on $D_1\cap D_2.$ Set $f_2=f_1$ in $ D_1$ and $f_2=g+ic_1$ in $ D_2$ it follows that $f_2\in O( D_1\cup D_2).$ By the same way we construct $f_m,$ $m=3,4,\cdots$\

For $m>0$ set $F_m=e^{f_m}$. The squence $(F_m)_m$ has a subsequence that converges locally uniformly in $D.$ Indeed let $K\subset D$ be a compact ball. Observe that $|F_m|=e^h$ in $D_m$ for all $m>0$ we infer that $F_m$ is uniformly bounded on $K.$ By Montel's theorem $(F_m)_m$ has a subsequence $(F_{m_k})_k$ that converges on $K$. In fact $(F_{m_k})_k$ converges locally uniformly in $D.$ \ \

To prove that $(F_{m_k})_k$ is convergent, it is enough to show that :\

1) it does not contain divergent subsequences\

2) all its convergent subsequences converge to the same limit.  \ \

First assume that there are a compact set $K'$ and a subsequence $(F_{m_{k'}})$ of $(F_{m_{k}})$ which does not converge on $K'$. Let $U$ be a relatively compact domain  in $D$ containing $K'$ and $K$. By Montel theorem's theorem $(F_{m_{k}})$  has a subsequence which converges uniformly in $U$  to a holomorphic function $g$.  So there is $\epsilon>0$ so that :

(1) $\sup_{K'}|F_{m_{k'}}-g|>\epsilon$  for all $k'$ big enough.\

This is impossible since the sequence $(F_{m_{k'}})$ is uniformly bounded on $U$ and by Montel's theorem its has a subsequence which converges uniformly in $U$ to a function $g'$. As $g'=g$ on $K$ then they coincide in $U.$ Equality (1) can not hold in other words such a subsequence $(F_{m_{k'}})$ does not exist.

Second let $(F_{m_{k'}})$ be a subsequence of $(F_{m_{k}})$ which converges locally uniformly in $D$ to $g'$ and $(F_{m_{k''}})$ be a subsequence of $(F_{m_{k}})$ which converges locally uniformly in $D$ to $g''.$ As $g'$ and $g''$ are holomorphic in $D$ and coincide in $K$ then $g'\equiv g''$ in $D.$

For $z\in D$ set $f(z)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} F_{m_k}(z)$ as the convergence is locally uniform we infer that $f$ is holomorphe and $|F_{m_k}|$ converges to $|f|$ as $k$ tends to infinite. Since $|F_{m_k}(z)|=e^{h(z)}$ for all $k$ we get $|f(z)|=e^{h(z)}$.

\end{proof}

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it, but is this answer relevant to the question at hand?